# Why the strange representation of 'NaN' in Sverige-Swedish CLR 4.0?

Tags: c#, unicode, nan

Using Sverige-Swedish as the primary language for the OS...

In a C# app for dotNET 4.0, when I call 'ToString' using "G" formatting and the current culture on a double that represents an invalid number ( NaN ), the resulting string is not "NaN" as might be expected. Instead, I get a string with three instances of U+00A4 ( "¤¤¤" ).

I get that the term in Swedish could be something other than "NaN" ( although when the OS is set to Deutschland-German, the string is "NaN" ) but this triplet of Unicode characters doesn't seem like a very useful way to represent the meaning of "not a number" in *any* language.

Can someone point me toward an explanation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be a bug. If you print a list of all strings that represent `NaN` for every culture, you see that every language except Swedish has either "NaN" or another meaningful description in the respective langauge:

```
foreach (CultureInfo ci in CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures))
{
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}:\t {1}", ci, double.NaN.ToString("g", ci)));
}
```

Comment: Ah, fantastic! My dev machine is busy doing a Windows update >_< so I can't try this just yet, but it sounds very plausible, so I'm going to give you the checkmark. Thanks!

Comment: I just noticed the checkmark wasn't green, so if I forgot to do that in a timely fashion, I apologize, and if it's SO's fault, well, I can't fix that. Either way, checkmark is now green. x-D